Meaning of "S. Epiph. her. 78" in the Douay-Rheims Bible (1635)
I’m currently trying to transcribe some notes from the 1635 Douay-Rheims Bible. I have a printed Facsimile I am working with at home, so far I have been able to understand most of the footnotes without issue. However, one has stumped me on the third chapter of Genesis. I transcribe it as follows: S. Epiph. her. 78. I assume that the “S.” is an abbreviation of “Sanctus” or “Sancta,” and “Epiph.” may be “Epiphany.” The context of the footnote is as follows: “She was mother rather of all the dying: but in figure of our Blessed Lady who is mother of Christ, life itself, she is called mother of the living. S. Epiph. her. 78.” I am providing an image in case I transcribed it wrong in the first place. Thanks in advance for the help! 

“S.Epiph.” is Saint Epiphanius of Salamis (c. 320–403) and “her.” is his book Against Heresies (c. 378), also known as the Panarion or “bread-basket”. The book catalogues 80 Christian groups or beliefs that Epiphanius considered heretical.
Chapter 78 of Against Heresies is “Against Antidicomarians”. It seems that the Antidicomarians, a sect of Christians in Arabia, denied the perpetual virginity of Mary, alleging that she “had relations with a man after Christ’s birth, I mean with Joseph himself” (78.1.1). The passage referenced by the annotater of the Douay-Rheims bible is this one:

It is Mary who is meant by the description of Eve, for she was symbolically given the title, “mother of the living.” For Eve was called “mother of the living”† in that passage, and this after being told, “Earth thou art, and unto earth shall thou return,”‡ following her transgression. And after this transgression, it was a surprise that she received this great title. Physically speaking, every human being in the world is born of that Eve; but here life itself has truly been born into the world of Mary, so that Mary brings forth the Living One and becomes the mother of the Living. Mary, then was called the “mother of the living” in a riddle.
Epiphanius of Salamis (c. 378). Against Heresies 78.18.1–3. Translated by Frank Williams (1987). The Panarion of Epiphanius of Salamis, volume 2, page 614. Leiden: Brill.
† Genesis 3:20. ‡ Genesis 3:19.

